# A PuTTY shortcut that automatically launches a profile?

Tags: windows, putty, shortcuts

How can I create a PuTTY shortcut that automatically launches a profile, so I can dial into a specific computer with one click?

Comment: It's not even necessary to have a saved session for that. `putty.exe user@host -p 42` and similar options can be used.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

From the [Putty FAQ](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-startsess):

> To run a PuTTY session saved under the name ‘mysession’, create a Windows shortcut that invokes PuTTY with a command line like `\path\name\to\putty.exe -load "mysession"`

---EDIT---

In Windows 7, the shortcut has to be in quotes like this:

"\path\name\to\putty.exe" -load "mysession"

Comment: Thanks, the same grammar to [PuTTYtray](https://puttytray.goeswhere.com/).

Answer (score 6):

In windows use this target for putty shortcut, for save username and password. Then load a saved session or add to Task Manager:
`"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe" -load "your_saved_session" -l "username@your_server_address" -pw "your_password"`

1. right click on putty shortcut
2. fill out "target" field of shortcut using above code (alter to your own properties).
3. click save button.

After that when you click on PuTTy shortcut it loads your session automatically using given username and password.

UPDATE: If you specified server ip or hostname in your selected putty profile you should not put your server address (..`@server_address`) in windows shortcut; correct shortcut is now:
`"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe" -load "your_saved_session" -l "username" -pw "your_password"`

Comment: Putting passwords in shortcut isn't a good idea. Type the password in putty window manually.

Comment: Yes Biswapriyo, but in educational purposes it is too boring type password many times!

Comment: Perhaps key authentication would be an alternative to passwords

Comment: In my case, I had to do it without `@your_server_address` as `-l "username" -pw "your_password"`.

Comment: Yes it seems to be a change in new versions of putty. @LalitFauzdar

Comment: You can use a password manager to store the password and hand it to PuTTY when necessary.

Answer (score 5):

I had referred to [Putty Connection Manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/puttycm/) as a useful addon, giving one click connects and tabbed windows, but it seems the app is dead and all the files removed from the hosting site.

While checking into this, I found a fork of the project, called superputty (see below) and a reference to KiTTY - a Win32 native version of PuTTY with extra features so here you go:

Superputty:https://github.com/jimradford/superputty

KiTTY: http://kitty.9bis.com/

Comment: There is no published files for puttycm, or homepages.

Comment: Yep - looks like the project has died - can't find the files anywhere. Shame. I have edited the post to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

[PuttyTray](https://puttytray.goeswhere.com/) is an alternative where you get sessions in the Windows quickjump list if you pin it to the taskbar. Mine is pinned at position 9, so I type Win+Alt+9 to show list of sessions and arrow key to select, then enter to launch.

It also has a bunch of other nice to have features.